# Cannot use system("cls"); in Xcode in mac

Tags: xcode

I tried to execute

```
system (cls):
```

in Xcode in mac, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Two problems.

1 - You didn't use quotes.

2 - The command on OS X is `clear`, not `cls`.

```
system("clear");
```

Instead of doing that, a better way is to add these #includes and also this `ClearScreen` function which sends the terminal a clear command directly, instead of starting a separate process. Cribbed from http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/4z18T05o/#POSIX

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <term.h>

void ClearScreen()   
{  
    if (!cur_term)
    {
      int result;
      setupterm( NULL, STDOUT_FILENO, &result );
      if (result <= 0) return;
    }

  putp( tigetstr( "clear" ) );   
}
```