# What function clears the screen on a mac terminal?

Tags: c, macos

I'm new to C and I do not own a mac, but I'm working on a personal project for someone who does and part of the project's requirements is that it clears the screen. The reason I need to clear the screen is that it's part of a loop that clears the screen and then prints something again (I'm trying to make a "ticking counter" of sorts.)

I know that system("cls") works well on my terminal (obviously any system function isn't ideal though), however, I know that she's on a Mac OS, and that the system() function is notoriously nonportable and I need this to work on a mac. I've scoured the internet trying to see what system functions clear the screen on a mac, and the most recent source I could find was from 2006. Considering how often the mac gets updated, I'm not surprised that 
I don't really need a solution that's elegant or secure, just an idea for something that works.  My compiler is MinGW with GCC for libraries.

Here's a sample of the relevant code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    time_t seconds; //variable declarations
    float days;
    float rate;
    int i;
    i = 3;
    char str[50];
    while (i > 2);
    {

        time(&seconds);

        days = (seconds - ((float)1584673594)) / (float)86400;

        rate = pow(1.05, days);

        rate = rate * 100;

        printf("\nCurrent Snuggle-Debt Balance: %f snuggles\n", rate);
        printf("Days passed:  %f \n", days);
        sleep(.5);
        system("cls");
```

Comment: Check this link solve your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27616522/cannot-use-systemcls-in-xcode-in-mac

Comment: Since I don't have access to a Mac, too, I can't say for sure. But you might like to try to output `'\f'` (form feed) that clears the terminal buffer on some terminals.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing a C program that uses standard input and output, and you need to do things like move the cursor around or clear part or all of the screen, the *curses* library is what you want. Curses is widely available and does what you want and much more. To clear the screen, just call the [`clear()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/clear.html) function. And that's just the beginning of [what you can do](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/curses.h.html).